# How to pass arguments to a python greenlet as additional arguments

Tags: python, python-stackless, greenlets

I'm looking for a way to pass function arguments through another function, in a manner identical to Stackless' `tasklet` instantiation:

```
stackless.tasklet(function_being_called)(*args)
```

So far the best way I've come up with is:

```
mylib.tasklet(function_being_called,*args)
```

which works, but is not identical to Stackless' syntax. I'm not sure where to look in the documentation to find out how to accomplish this (hence the rather ambiguous title for this question). Is this even possible, or is it part of Stackless' changes to the interpreter?

EDIT: I'm now aware that there is an approach which will work for functions, but I'm unsure if it will work in my case. I'm using the greenlet library: greenlet threads obtain args when the greenlet is `switch()`ed to, not on instantiation. Calling them as shown below results in

`TypeError: 'greenlet.greenlet' object is not callable`.

Using `greenlet.greenlet(function(args))` (still not right syntax) executes immediately and still requires args in the `switch()` method. Hence I currently store variables in-class, using the syntax shown above, to pass when calling `switch()`. Hope this doesn't change the question too much!

As requested, here is the code in question. 
First, a variant on eri's answer (DISCLAIMER: I've never used decorators before):

```
import greenlet # Background "greenlet" threadlet library

_scheduled = [] # Scheduler queue

def newtasklet(func): # Returns a greenlet-making function & switch() arguments. 
    def inner(*args,**kwargs):
        newgreenlet = greenlet.greenlet(func,None)
        return newgreenlet,args,kwargs
    return inner

class tasklet():
    def __init__(self,function=None):
        global _scheduled 
        initializer = newtasklet(function)
        self.greenlet,self.variables,self.kvars = initializer()
        _scheduled.append(self)
        self.blocked = False

tasklet(print)("A simple test using the print function.")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#604>", line 1, in <module>
    tasklet(print)("A simple test using the print function.")
TypeError: 'tasklet' object is not callable
```

Original code (working but not syntactically ideal):

```
class tasklet(): 
    def __init__(self,function=None,*variables,parent=None):
        global _scheduled
        self.greenlet = greenlet.greenlet(function,parent)
        self.variables = variables
        _scheduled.append(self)
        self.blocked = False

>>> tasklet(print,"A simple test using the print function.")
<__main__.tasklet object at 0x7f352280e610>
>>> a = _scheduled.pop()
>>> a.greenlet.switch(*a.variables)
A simple test using the print function.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Stackless, but what's happening there is that the `tasklet` functions returns a reference to the function, that is then called by the interpreter with the *args.

An example:

```
def return_the_method(method):
    return method

def add_two(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2
```

If you have this, then run `return_the_method(add_two)(1, 2)`, you'll get `3`.

Answer (score 1):

stackless.tasklet is decorator. Rewrite your function as decorator.

```
def tasklet(f):
  def inner(*args,**kwargs):
    t= Thread(target=f,args=args,kwargs=kwargs)
    t.start()
    return t
  return inner


task=tasklet(your_func)(arg)
task.join()
```

It runs your_func in separate thread and returns thread instance.

Comment: Do you know if this will work with greenlets in addition to threads? I tried a variant where `__init__()` calls `tasklet,args,kwargs = newtasklet(function)`, where
`def newtasklet(func): def inner(*args,*kwargs): newgreenlet = greenlet.greenlet(function,parent); return newgreenlet,args,kwargs`
 -- but as I should have predicted, `'function' object is not iterable`.

Comment: @HumblePenguin difficult to understand that you mean in single line code. Pastebin it please with part of context.

Comment: @HumblePenguin Or better yet include it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure to return a function from `mylib.tasklet`:

```
>>> def call_me(func):
        # do something here, like spawn a thread
        return func

>>> def being_called(str1, str2, str3):
        print str1
        print str2
        print str3

>>> call_me(being_called)('a', 'b', 'c')
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used stackless before, but `stackless.tasklet(function_being_called)` is returning a function object that is being given the parameters `(*args)`.  If you want the syntax to be the same for your tasklet, then `mylib.tasklet` should return a function.

For example:

```
def inner(*args):
    print '|'.join(args)

def foo(func):
    return func

foo(inner)('hello', 'world')
```

Outputs:

```
hello|world
```

Comment: It does indeed return a function -- or at least, instantiates it. In the initialization of the tasklet, it assigns it a position in a queue so that it's not lost, which makes it behave similarly to Stackless (which is my goal).

Comment: Hmm, are you unable to return the function and still have that behavior?

Comment: Actually, I misspoke. It instantiates a class. See edited question; as far as "returning a function" goes, I'm not sure I can implement it, because (unlike the greenlet library) I don't recall anywhere in Stackless usage where the `tasklet` instantiation was returned to a variable. Since they were spawned directly, e.g. `stackless.tasklet(func)(*args)`, I'd be unsure how to keep track of the tasklets since they would be "returned" directly to the program body. (Which to my mind suggests that _here_ at least was some interpreter modification!)

Answer (score 0):

import greenlet # Background "greenlet" threadlet library

_scheduled = [] # Scheduler queue

def newtasklet(func): # Returns a greenlet-making function & switch() arguments. 
    def inner(*args,**kwargs):
        newgreenlet = greenlet.greenlet(func,None)
        return newgreenlet,args,kwargs
    return inner

class tasklet():
    def **init**(self,function=None):
        global _scheduled 
        initializer = newtasklet(function)
        self.greenlet,self.variables,self.kvars = initializer()
        _scheduled.append(self)
        self.blocked = False
    def **call**(self, function=None):
        return function

def imprime(a):
    print a

tasklet(imprime)("A simple test using the print function.")